# Wordpress article with >200 comments shows display error only in Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, comments

[This article on a customer's website](http://www.netzwerk-frauengesundheit.com/progesteron-das-hormon-der-weisheit-richtig-einsetzen/) has over 200 comments and somehow several comments **at the very bottom of this article** are merged - **but only in Firefox**. Chrome and IE look OK.

This appears to be the only article with this issue and I assume it is due to the number of comments.

Source code looks ok to me...

Website is running WordPress 3.0.4. (not convinced that an update will do any good). Template is Arthemia. No active plugins which have an effect on the comments section.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if 200+

```
div class="commentlist"
```

are nested instead of being closed after each comment.

Seemingly Firefox stops the rendering of those 200+ levels before it gets frozen to a halt.
Chrome renders them all but is struggling hard with it as well.

Also div between li elements are not allowed. The whole comment list looks pretty messed up if you ask me.

i'd say there's somethere a foreach loop building the commentlist.
The div tag

```
div class="commentlist"
```

is inside that loop but needs to be outside.
At least that's where I would search for the bug.

Comment: Thanks! You were correct, there were several div issues in the comments php file which I corrected based on your advice. Thanks again!